# Pipreqs to generate requirements.txt not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, requirements.txt

I am trying to get requirements.txt file for my ipynb notebook using `$ pipreqs user/doc/test`. My file is in the location user/doc/test/run.ipynb. There is no other file in the test folder except run.ipynb. But i keep getting the error  `No such file or directory: 'user/doc/test\\requirements.txt'`. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one file in your directory, you can try running just

```
pipreqs
```

> INFO: Successfully saved requirements file in /home/your-path/ipynb-examples/requirements.txt

after going inside the directory having that single ipynb file, it will give your requirements.txt